# How to have a numeric text box of length 5 for editing a cell in angular grid

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I am new to AngularJS

I have a grid that displays data when I click on an edit button to make a cell editable. Now I want to allow only decimal or numbers and length should be only 5 in it . Please see the picture.

That's my code in controller

```
 { field: 'fam_coinsurance', width: '15%', displayName: 'Fam Coinsurance',type: 'number', cellFilter: 'number: 3', enableCellEdit: true, cellEditableCondition: $scope.canEdit }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STW4o.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `editableCellTemplate` property to define a custom cell template to use when editing that field. This could use the HTML5 "numeric" input with a "max" of "99999" to only allow 5 digits.

```
 editableCellTemplate: '<input type="number" max="99999" ui-grid-editor ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD">'
```

Please see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrkt5dk7/2/) for an example - here the "age" column uses the custom cell template.

Answer (score 0):

try this in grid options

`editableCellTemplate: <input ui-grid-editor ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" ng-minlength="12" ng-maxlength="14" minlength="12" maxlength="14">`

here work! Thanks @Ian A.